# Django template get first?

Tags: django, templatetags

I need to do something like

```
{{ article.product.images.first.image.url }}
```

In my template, but there is no "first" (`images` is a `RelatedManager` for which I found very little documentation).

Is there another way to do this? I can get the first model with

```
{{ article.product.images.get_query_set|first }}
```

But then I need to dig a few properties deeper, and that doesn't work.

---

If it helps, my image model looks like this:

```
class ComponentImage(models.Model):
    component = models.ForeignKey(Component, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
```

And `article.product` is a `Component`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about `{{article.product.images.all.0.image.url}}`' ?

This is the same as the python expression `article.product.images.all[0].image.url`.

Another option is to add a method to the product model that returns `images[0].image.url`

Comment: Genius! I was thinking about how I could access `[0]` but I wasn't sure of the proper syntax. You actually need a `.all.` in there too, like `{{article.product.images.all.0.image.url}}` to make it work.